# Why are named exports for static class properties undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
.
├── myClass.js
├── myModule.js
└── index.js
```

```js
// index.js
import myModule from './myModule.js'
import myClass from './myClass.js'

myClass.init()
myModule()
```

```js
// myModule.js
import A, { prop1 } from './myClass.js'
export default () => {
    console.log("A.prop1 is: ", A.prop1)
    console.log("while prop1 is: ", prop1)
}
```

```js
// myClass.js
export default class A {
    static prop1
    static init() {
        this.prop1 = 88
    }
}
export const { prop1 } = A
```

When I run my code,

```
node index.js
```

I see the following output:

```
A.prop1 is:  88
while prop1 is:  undefined
```

My question is, why is `prop1` (the named export) `undefined` while the default export one has a value?

Isn't JavaScript doing *referencing* here?

[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/zealous-pike-wsmld4) View on codeSandbox:

[image]

Isn't JavaScript supposed to do object referencing here? so, it's not like a primitive, instead, it acts as an object reference?

*And by the way, I was using TypeScript, and even TypeScript couldn't detect that `prop1` (the named export) could be undefined, instead it thought like me that it was a `number`. - not related but just a side note.*

Answer (score 4):

```
export const { prop1 } = A
```

is equivalent to

```
export const prop1 = A.prop1;
```

Since this happens before `A.init()` is called, it uses the initial value of `prop1`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Isn't JavaScript supposed to do variable reference here? so, it's not like a primitive, instead it acts as an object?

Comment: There's no such thing as references to variables or properties. References are to objects.

Comment: If I changed prop1 to be an object, an empty object, and decided to assign properties to it from the `init()` method, will this make the named export `prop1` the current actual object instead of `{}` ?

Comment: @Normal if you give the default value to be an object and then manipulate it, it would have worked. i.e, Had you done something like this it would have taken the new value https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/named-exports-static-props-forked-6jgsh7?file=%2FmyClass.js%3A10%2C28

Answer (score 1):

`import A, { prop1 } from './myClass.js'` runs before `myClass.init()` runs.
At this point the value of `prop1` has already been exported.
While A still refers to the class and hence can make benefit of `myClass.init()`, `prop1` in itself is just a **primitive variable** that has been exported from another file. It's value is already decided and does not refer to anything else but `undefined`.